# Ubuntu 13.10 no wired internet connection

Tags: networking, wired

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10. This is my first OS other than windows. I'm able to connect to wifi but not via LAN.
Could any please help me understand the issue... I read through a lot but my bad I dont understand linux or codes or terminal.

Could anyone please explain what needs to be done and how in simple...

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please paste the output of `ifconfig` here? http://paste.ubuntu.com/ -- you can either copy paste it from the terminal or run something like `ifconfig >> /home/YOURNAME/out.txt` to get it in a text file if you prefer that.

Comment: YOu have to introduce yourself with `ifconfig` command. It is easy. May be `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` will be enough for you.

Comment: Danatela, it worked ... Thanks a lot...I owe you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and write sudo ifconfig eth0 up. Now you will see a message "wired connection 1 - connected" and then edit the required connections.